# Is there a way to post very large JSON payloads through AWS API Gateway?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a REST API that exposes a POST endpoint and accepts JSON messages. The API then triggers a Lambda function in .Net Core 3.1 that does some processing with the payload.

The structure for the JSON message is something like:

```
{
 Code: "string",
 Name: "string",
 Items: []
}
```

The collection of Items could be very large.

As has happened to many others before, I have came across some AWS limitations regarding payload sizes. The payload size limit for AWS API Gateway is 10 MB and for Lambda functions is 6 MB.

I have looked online and read about the work around using pre-signed S3 URLs but I am not sure these will work in my scenario.

The API I currently have in place returns a 400 BadRequest when data is wrong or missing in the JSON payload. I don't see how I could simulate this with pre-signed S3 URLs and uploading directly to S3.

In addition, even with the payload in S3, I would still need a Lambda function to read it and process it.

Finally, the API integrates with a 3rd party so making them post to 2 different URLs is not a desired solution.

Any ideas on how can I make the API work with a very large JSON message?

Comment: "I have looked online and read about the work around using pre-signed S3 URLs but I am not sure these will work in my scenario."

What exactly blocks you from using a pre-signed S3 URL in your scenario ?

Comment: Could you investigate compressing the payload prior to sending through API Gateway, e.g. using gzip. JSON is typically very compressible. Obviously reverse that in the target Lambda. Have not tested this but could not find anything definitive that says it won't work.

Comment: @JBernales How would you return a 400 BasRequest using the pre-signed S3 URLs if for example a Required property in the payload was missing?

Answer (score 1):

> The payload size limit for AWS API Gateway is 10 MB and for Lambda functions is 6 MB.

Yes correct, there are some imits. The reason is that the payload is passed as a single json to the lambda fn and there is no option for more memory-friendly streaming. If we want the generous free-tier, we have to accept some limits.

> I don't see how I could simulate this with pre-signed S3 URLs and uploading directly to S3

it's not simulating the same scenario, different approach is needed. Basically the client uploads the content to S3 and a lamba is invoked as an S3 notification event about the new content (asynchronously).

Example steps:

1. the client calls an api to get the [presigned url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html)
2. the client uploads the content
3. S3 invokes a lambda fn as part of the [S3 Event Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)  As an input the lambda receives the S3 object key and the lambda will have to read/download the content itself.

The downside is that if the client is expecting some response from the processing, then the request and processing needs to be paired together somehow (using filename, using some persisted data in a DB,...)

> making them post to 2 different URLs is not a desired solution

We forced our partners to work that way and.. it is working. If you are not happy with the limits and the approach,  you can expose your own server (not lambda) and enforce your own limits or support the streaming.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand how this would work to upload files such as videos or images, but I was asking if there would be a way to simulate a standard API call were you need to return a response such as a 400 BadRequest.

The presign URL would return a 200 Success when the content is successfully uploaded but the Lambda function that is triggered afterwards to actually process the payload wouldn't be able to return anything to the 3rd party.

Comment: @g0np no, you cannot "simulate" the behavior, not with APIGW and Lambda. The async event may even take several minutes to be received. So when passing larger content, you can either expose your own server (with higher limits or streaming support) or turn to the async processing - where the client needs to poll for the processing result.  Just an idea - if the payload is text (json, xml), maybe you could compress the document. But it's just a workaround, there will be always a limit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input.

What we ended up doing is making the 3rd party compress their JSON before sending it to us.

We then unzip it, serialize it into the original dto and run a Validator to check the model is valid.

If validations fail, we return a BadRequest() with the validation errors. Otherwise we return an Accepted()